My model simulates correctly in Gazebo Harmonic, but it behaves erratically in Gazebo 11
What could be causing this issue?
This is my model repository：
https://github.com/0eclipse0/robot2.git
thanks！

Do you realize that you link to an empty GitHub repository?

It is hard to debug without having the terminal log outputs. Can you please edit you question and add it?
I think you could try the following approaches to fix it :
1- Are you sourcing the workspace before launching the robot in Gazebo? Perhaps the meshes path are not bing found.
2 - You can check if your urdf has some issue:
check_urdf path_to_urdf/robot2.urdf

3- Confirm the robot structure is correct on rviz2:
ros2 launch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=path_to_urdf/robot2.urdf

-------CHECKING THE SDF YOU HAVE----------
You just uploaded the SDF to GitHub, don`t you have the urdf?
4- Validate the robot2.sdf:
The CMD below checks the syntax and structural issues in your SDF file:
gz sdf -k path_to_sdf/robot2.sdf

5- If you have the urdf convert it to SDF, to check if some issue will raise during conversion. If not just use it instead the one you have on GitHub:
gz sdf -p path_to_urdf/robot2.urdf

6- Run the SDF with Verbose logging:
gz server path_to_sdf/robot2.sdf --verbose

7 - I would check the meshes permission and assign super user permissions to them:
chmod 777 meshes/chengg_down.STL

chmod 777 meshes/chengg_up.STL

chmod 777 meshes/cl1.STL

chmod 777 meshes/jiaol_gan.STL

8- Install every package related-needed from gazebo and from SDF:
sudo apt-get install ros-distro-gazebo*

sudo apt-get install libsdformat*

Finally source the distro-root pkgs to enable the ones installed:
source /opt/ros/distro/setup.bash


thanks for your response, In gazebo11, there is no log output, but when I zoom out the model, it works. i dont know why.
